# How to scroll to start in a CollectionView with ScrollTo?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a `CollectionView` in which I add new elements by pressing a `Button`. The new elements are added on top of each other. What I want to do is that every time a new element is added, it scrolls to the last element added above.

`scrollTo` is in a try clause and every time I put this line it accesses the catch and it doesn't work:

```
View.CollectionView.ScrollTo(ScrollToPosition.Start);
```

I tried with `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode` in xaml with all options but don't scrolls up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CollectionView.ScrollTo` Method has the following overloads

```
ScrollTo(Int32, Int32, ScrollToPosition, Boolean)   
ScrollTo(Object, Object, ScrollToPosition, Boolean)
```

So you need to pass the index or model of the item that you want to scrolol to .

For example

```
View.CollectionView.ScrollTo(0);
```

For more details you could check [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/scrolling)